# Dramatic decrease in performance for Postgres query on Google SQL compared to my laptop. Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, google-cloud-sql

A rather complex (depending on standards) query running on a table with about 1M records. Creating some temporary tables and building arrays and jsonb.

On localhost I get average of 2.5 seconds.
On Google SQL I get 17-19 seconds.

Note:

1. Other queries, like simple selects, are faster on server than on local. As it should.
2. I did run vacuum, rebuilded all index, checked for hanging process. All good.
3. I played with resources. Created an instance with 8 VCPU and 16Gb Ram. Almost same result.
4. I checked proc, mem, disc. No problem.

Here are the results from `explain analyse`for the most slow query.[image: Slow query]
and here for local one [image: Localhost. Ok speed.]

What could possibly be?

*Possible duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503324/google-cloud-sql-is-slow-mysql-instance-with-10gb-ram-is-20x-slower-than-macboo) but it's not answered, has 2 years and has no tags. I'll try my luck.*

L.E. explain analyse verbose in text

```
Update on public.customers  (cost=30.38..207.32 rows=127 width=104) (actual time=13105.151..13105.154 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning Time: 1.852 ms
Execution Time: 13105.306 ms
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=30.38..207.32 rows=127 width=104) (actual time=316.371..13091.937 rows=42 loops=1)
"        Output: customers.id, customers.company_id, customers.sap_id, customers.parent_sap_id, jsonb_set(customers.stats, '{consolidatedSales}'::text[], jsonb_build_array(calculateconsolidatedstats(customers.id, customers.sap_id, ((date_part('year'::text, (CURRENT_DATE)::timestamp without time zone) - '2'::double precision))::integer), calculateconsolidatedstats(customers.id, customers.sap_id, ((date_part('year'::text, (CURRENT_DATE)::timestamp without time zone) - '1'::double precision))::integer), calculateconsolidatedstats(customers.id, customers.sap_id, (date_part('year'::text, (CURRENT_DATE)::timestamp without time zone))::integer)), true), customers.tags, customers.account_manager_id, customers.created_by_id, customers.customer_status_id, customers.created_at, customers.updated_at, customers.ctid, parents_with_sales.ctid"
        Inner Unique: true
        Hash Cond: (customers.id = parents_with_sales.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on public.customers  (cost=0.00..74.54 rows=254 width=924) (actual time=0.021..0.419 rows=254 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=27.88..27.88 rows=200 width=10) (actual time=0.086..0.088 rows=42 loops=1)
"              Output: parents_with_sales.ctid, parents_with_sales.id"
"              Output: customers.id, customers.company_id, customers.sap_id, customers.parent_sap_id, customers.stats, customers.tags, customers.account_manager_id, customers.created_by_id, customers.customer_status_id, customers.created_at, customers.updated_at, customers.ctid"
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=25.88..27.88 rows=200 width=10) (actual time=0.059..0.072 rows=42 loops=1)
"                    Output: parents_with_sales.ctid, parents_with_sales.id"
                    Group Key: parents_with_sales.id
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on pg_temp_7.parents_with_sales  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=10) (actual time=0.010..0.019 rows=42 loops=1)
"                          Output: parents_with_sales.ctid, parents_with_sales.id"
```

Cloud Logging results for the culprit query that takes 12s
[image: cloud logging results]

Comment: 1) `explain (analyse, verbose, buffers, settings) ...` for more details; 2) result in text please.

Comment: @marian.vladoi: How would that work with PostgreSQL?

Comment: I would recommend to [Monitor slow queries in PosgreSQL with Cloud Logging and Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138337/logging-slow-queries-on-google-cloud-sql-postgresql-instances) in order to understand better the performance.

Comment: @Abelisto - done. See L.E.

Comment: @marian.vladoi  - done. Not sure how it helps, but I add it.

Comment: It is hard to think of a purely PostgreSQL explanation for this.  Seems like your cloud provider is having some issues.  How reproducible is this?  (BTW, neither table seems to be anywhere near 1 million rows.)

Comment: @jjanes This table (it is only 1 in 2 scenarios) is running against a temporary table with customers and the functions runs against the invoices table that has about 1M rows.
I agree with you that the issues may be with the gcloud. I have no special settings on my laptop and a 8x difference is too much. Other queries are faster, as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
The issue was in the version.

Short version: deploying on v11 and all went back to normal. The server is faster than my laptop, as it should.

Long version:

- tried a fresh install in a VMS (2 vcpu, 4Gb ram). I got 20+ seconds, even worst than in managed instance. Increased the resources to 16proc, 64Gb ram and 500Gb SSD (for IO), all are maximum allowed in that region. The result was astonishing... the time **increased** to 25 sec.
- went to Digital Ocean: Managed instance, 1VCPU and 3.6 Gb Ram - 12 seconds (this guys are super good!). Better but still under-performing. Increased the instance resources to max allowed - no noticeable improvement.
- did not tried AWS. Too expensive for an experiment. :-)
- Finally, I realized that the version I have installed locally is 11 not 12, as I thought. Went back to gcloud and tried with an instance running v11 and... miracle. Works like charm.

Will dig in some other time on "why on earth is v12 and v13 so much slower".

Comment: Sorry for digging up an old thread. But did you ever find out the reason for why it's slower on v13 vs v11?

Comment: Yes. I forgot it meanwhile but it was something about the way new pg is treating temporary tables. Or something like that. Too advanced for me, to be honest. :-)

Comment: Hey SharpBCD, did you end up staying in PGv11? We are setting up a new system using CloudSQL and our initial tests using both PGv11 and 14 are pretty bad, at around 3-7 TPS from pgbench tests, wonder if you have any other info to share about the performance in the longer run

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being able to provide you with more helpful info. On my tests PG11 was performing much better for all queries so there was no reason to upgrade it at that time.
Most probably you'll need to rewrite all complex queries to meet the PG14 model. I chouse not to for that project.